# Exposed drop down menu reopens after language change

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

For some reason, the menu keeps opening when i change the language.

The XML of menu looks like this:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/language_menu"
    style="@style/ExposedDropdownMenuStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/sixteen_dp_margin"
    android:hint="@string/language">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/language_menu_auto_complete"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:dropDownSelector="@drawable/language_dropdown_bg"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:paddingStart="24dp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/sixteen_dp_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/sixteen_dp_margin" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

I am populating menu with choices in onResume() of a fragment:

```
val languages = resources.getStringArray(R.array.app_languages)
val adapter = ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), R.layout.language_list_item, languages)
binding.languageMenuAutoComplete.setAdapter(adapter)
```

The item selection listener looks like this:

```
binding.languageMenuAutoComplete.setOnItemClickListener { _, _, position, _ ->
    // position 0 = english, 1 = ukrainian, 2 = russian
    val localeList = when (position) {
        1 -> LocaleListCompat.forLanguageTags("uk")
        2 -> LocaleListCompat.forLanguageTags("ru")
        else -> LocaleListCompat.forLanguageTags("en")
    }
    AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales(localeList)
}
```

So after language is changed the drop down menu opens by itself. Have no idea why...

I've tryed so far:

- removing focus
- dismissing drop down (onResume, onDestroy, onCreate etc.)

Maybe someone's encountered this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Omg, I found a solution) After changing language I call the killer trio:                clearListSelection(), dismissDropDown(), clearFocus(). Not sure which one helped, because calling one of them at a time doesn't work.

Here the code example:

```
binding.languageMenuAutoComplete.apply {
    // Setting popup menu background
    setDropDownBackgroundDrawable(
        ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(
            resources,
            R.drawable.language_dropdown_bg,
            null
        )
    )
    setOnItemClickListener { _, _, position, _ ->
        // position 0 = english, 1 = ukrainian, 2 = russian
        val localeList = when (position) {
            1 -> LocaleListCompat.forLanguageTags("uk")
            2 -> LocaleListCompat.forLanguageTags("ru")
            else -> LocaleListCompat.forLanguageTags("en")
        }
        AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales(localeList)
        this.clearListSelection()
        this.dismissDropDown()
        this.clearFocus()
    }
```